# Is it possible to have multiple row separators in Talend?

Tags: talend

I'm facing a challenge for one of my first projects as a junior dev. I'm using Talend to open some metadata files that have a series of "key=value" pairs within the files. I eventually need to transform the metadata and write it as a new row in an Excel file.

The metadata file looks something like this:

```
 DOCTYPE=some_data
 DOCNBR=some_data
 DOCREV=some_data
 DOCBASE=some_data
 DOCNAME=some_data
 RELEASE=some_data
 DWG=TYPE=2;NAME=some_data;SIZE=some_data
 DESCRIPTION=some_data
```

Line 7 of the example above (DWG=TYPE=2;NAME=some_data;SIZE=some_data) is what I'm stuck on when I'm attempting to create a new delimited metadata file, using "=" as the field separator and "\n" as the row separator.

Is there a way to have multiple row separators to include ";" so that I could have the other items on line 7 on their own rows?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

Write a regex which include \n and ; both and give it to the field delimiter field

Comment: When I write "\n|;" in the row separator field, I don't get anything in the file preview.